# Como adicionar uma classe css a um elemento de acordo com a página acessada no vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Bom Dia Senhores. Estou com uma pequena dificuldade com o Vue.js, quero entender como posso colocar a classe "active" num elemento `li` de acordo com a rota ativa no momento.

Tenho um menu que é gerado dinamicamente através de um Loop no `vue.js` e gostaria de saber como posso aplicar a classe `active` de acordo com o link ativo no momento ao elemento `li` correto que está sendo renderizado.

Ex:

```
<li v-for="rota in rotas" class="active">
      <router-link :to="rota.path">
           <i :class="rota.icone"></i>
           <p>{{ rota.titulo }}</p>
      </router-link>
 </li>
```

Eu quero que o atributo **`class="active"`**  seja aplicado somente ao menu correspondente a rota que está ativa no navegador.

Comment: Vejam este exemplo de como quero que fique na imagem a seguir: http://imgur.com/a/ynZSA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<router-link tag="li" to="route-here">
  <a>meu botão</a>
</router-link>
```

Irá gerar um li, contendo o  com o link dentro.
caso o a interno esteja ativo, o li de fora recebe a classe `.active`.

Answer (score 0):

Vale iniciar dizendo que o `Router` já faz isso para o `<router-link>`. Se a rota for a mesma do `router-link`, ele já adiciona a classe `active` automativamente.

No caso de você precisar mesmo que seja aplicado no `<li>`, uma possibilidade é você usar um `method` que compara a rota com um parametro. [Veja nesse link](https://jsfiddle.net/educkf/jdd1bcyb/) tem um exemplo funcional disso.

Answer (score 0):

Essa técnica funciona quando a gente faz o menu estático. No meu caso, gerei um menu dinâmico, de acordo com as rotas que tenho no meu arquivo **`rotas.js`** ele é o responsável pela declaração de rotas no meu sistema, daí importo ele em um componente principal (**`App.vue`**) e dentro deste arquivo passo as **rotas** como **propriedade** para o módulo **sidebar.vue**, ou seja, o menu se baseia na quantidade de rotas existentes, no seu exemplo o menu é estático então seu exemplo se aplicou perfeitamente, já de modo dinâmico eu não poderia passar a propriedade dessa forma no *atributo HTML*, uma vez que este está num laço de repetição **`v-for`**.

De qualquer forma, eu consegui uma solução para isso. Veja aqui como fiz.
Na [documentação](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) do **vue.js** eles ensinam a passar um objeto para a propriedade `class` e então neste objeto a propriedade `active` responsável por aplicar a **classe `active`** ao meu elemento HTML verifica se o valor do atributo ***`isActive`*** é verdadeiro (`true`) e daí aplica ou não, uma vez que entendi isso, decidi transformar o atributo em uma função e passar para ela o valor do atributo `rota.path` que está sendo executado no momento em que o loop é feito.
Um erro que havia ocorrido neste momento, é que quando `rota.path` recebia o valor da rota inicial `''`, ele não aplicava classe alguma ao elemento, pois o valor é "vazio". Então fiz uma verificação ternária e se o valor fosse vazio ou `''` o parâmetro passado para **`isActive`** seria `/`, fazendo com que a função retornasse **`true`** e o link da Home Page funcionasse igual aos demais.

Meu **HTML** Ficou assim:

```
<li v-for="rota in rotas" :class="{ active: isActive(rota.path ? rota.path : '/') }">
    <router-link :to="rota.path ? rota.path : '/'">
        <i :class="rota.icone"></i>
        <p>{{ rota.titulo }}</p>
    </router-link>
 </li>
```

e meu código **JavaScript** ficou assim:

```
<script>
 props:['rotas'],
    data(){
        return{
            isActive: function(path){
                if(this.$route.path == path){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Dessa forma ele fica ativo em todos os links que possuem rotas e também no HOME que neste caso é uma rota vazia.

No caso da propriedade **`rotas`** é porque eu recebo seus dados de outro componente.
O meu arquivo de rotas **(rotas.js)** fica basicamente asim:

```
import Home from './modulos/pages/Home.vue';
import Conta from './modulos/pages/Conta.vue';
import Perfil from './modulos/pages/Perfil.vue';


export const routes = [
    {path:'', component: Home, titulo: 'Home', icone: 'pe-7s-graph' },
    {path:'/conta', component: Conta, titulo: 'Conta', icone: 'pe-7s-user'},
    {path:'/perfil', component: Perfil, titulo: 'Perfil', icone: 'pe-7s-user'}
];
```